# Finding Radii of Convergence for $\sum a_n z^{2n}$ and $\sum a_n^2 z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

**Setting:** Let $\sum a_n z^n$ have radius of convergence $R$.  We have that

$$
R = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_n \right|^{1/n}}
$$

via Hadamard's formula for the radius of convergence.

**Question:** What are the radii of convergence for (i) $\sum a_n z^{2n}$ and (ii) $\sum a_n^2 z^n$?

**Attempt for $\sum a_n^2 z^n$:**

1. For ease of notation, let $R_1$ and $R_2$ denote the radii of convergence for power series $\sum a_n z^{2n}$ and $\sum a_n^2 z^n$ respectively.
2. From Hadamard's formula, we then have

   $$
   R_2 = \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_n^2 \right|^{1/n}} = \left( \frac{1}{\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\limsup} \left|a_n \right|^{1/n}} \right)^2 = R^2
   $$

But what about $R_1$?

Comment: Consider using \limsup to get $\limsup$ instead of $limsup$.

Comment: TooOldForMath -- I just corrected Hadamard's formula.

Comment: Use the D'Alembert property again!

Comment: Quote from a comment on your previous quite receznt question: "there are much simpler and shorter approaches than Hadamard's formula (a vastly overrated tool, based on the questions on this site)."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your calculation for the second is correct. For the first one note that
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^{2n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n z^n$$

with $b_n=a_{k}$ if $n=2k$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b_n=0$ otherwise.

Then

$$R_1=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}|b_n|^{1/n}}=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|^{1/(2n)}}=\left(\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} |a_n|^{1/n}}\right)^{1/2}=R^{1/2}$$

Comment: could you explain why in the second fraction the (2n) part does not turn in to (2k)

Answer (score 3):

Let $w=z^2$. Then the first series converges for $|w|<R$, thus...